# Using binder1st with custom functor

Tags: c++, functor

I'd like to bind the first argument of my print functor to 0:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

class Print : public std::binary_function<int,int,void>{
public:
    void operator()(int val1, int val2)
    {   
        cout << val1 + val2 << endl;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    Print print;
    binder1st(print,0) f; //this is line 16
    f(3);  //should print 3
}
```

The program above (based on an example from [C++ Primer Plus](http://books.google.pl/books?id=eC-iLe_iET8C&pg=PA1033&dq=binder1st+example&hl=en&sa=X&ei=s98NUtq_HsjxsgbIuoCgBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=binder1st%20example&f=false)) does not compile:

```
line16 : error : missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
```

What is wrong?

I don't want to use C++11 nor boost features.

Edited: operator() return type has been changed from bool to void for simplicity

Comment: You can use `bind1st(print, 0)(3);` and then you don't have to specify the template arguments yourself.

Comment: Why binder1st instead of bind1st (which can deduce the template args)?

Comment: @doctorlove: because I want to convert print(int,int) into f(int) and then using f many times. Is it possible with bind1st?

Comment: @cpp: you could still use `bind1st` if you introduce a new function: `template<typename F> void foo(F f) { f(3); /* Rest of the calls. */ }` and then do `foo(bind1st(print, 0))` later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you are missing template arguments before the `(`
This is what you want

```
std::binder1st<Print> f(print, 0);
```

However, you also need to make your `operator()` const as follows

```
bool operator()(int val1, int val2) const
```

Finally, this function needs to return something.

Answer (score 2):

`binder1st` needs template-arguments, try

```
 binder1st<Print> f(print, 0);
```

See the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/binder1st/) here.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  binder1st < equal_to<int> > equal_to_10 (equal_to<int>(),10);
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30,40,50,10};
  int cx;
  cx = count_if (numbers,numbers+6,equal_to_10);
  cout << "There are " << cx << " elements equal to 10.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::binder1st`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binder12) is a class template, so it needs a template parameter.

```
binder1st<Print> f(print,0);
//       ^^^^^^^
```

But if you really want to bind the second argument, then you need to use the aptly named `std::binder2nd`.

Comment: Thanx, but it still does not compile. The error is now `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘f’` at line 16

Comment: Doesn't the (print, 0) need to go *after* f for binder1st?

Comment: @cpp sorry, I had a typo. It is fixed. But note that your `bool operator()` **must** return a `bool`, and should be `const`. You aren't returning anything.

Comment: @juanchopanza The OP made you do it ;-)

Comment: @doctorlove Right, that was some lazy copy and pasting from my side!

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanx I edited this. The function call operator should return void.